# Execute command with sudo via PHP

Tags: php, sudo

I have scripts in `/etc/init.d/` that I use to control game servers and I would like to build a simple web interface to call those scripts. My sudoers file contains something like

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/starbound start stop
```

When I execute `sudo /etc/init.d/starbound start` within PHP, nothing happens. Am I missing something? Trying to access paths my PHP user is not allowed to usually gives me the appropriate warnings at least.

Comment: Have a try with an absolute path to the `sudo` executable.

Comment: ^ You can use `which sudo` to find the full path to sudo if you aren't sure where it is.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I also checked if the required files are accessible and `is_executable("/usr/bin/sudo");` says `true` so does `is_executable("/etc/init.d/starbound");`

Comment: Should've looked into the auth.log which reads:

`Jun  7 20:33:11 smares sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Jun  7 20:33:11 smares sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [www-data]
Jun  7 20:33:11 smares sudo: www-data : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/www/smares.de/ajax ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/starbound start`

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem lies in the sudoers file. If I remove the `start stop`, it works.

So a correct sudoers could look like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias GAMES = /etc/init.d/ark_thecenter start, \
                   /etc/init.d/ark_thecenter stop, \
                   /etc/init.d/ark_theisland start, \
                   /etc/init.d/ark_theisland stop, \
                   /etc/init.d/starbound start, \
                   /etc/init.d/starbound stop

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: GAMES
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo` requires that you input your password when you run a command. By running `sudo` with `exec()` you aren't providing the password to `sudo` and cannot run the command with root level privileges.

[Ubuntu.SE provides a way to pass the password to sudo in a single command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo), but the result is a little messy when implemented with PHP because the `Password:` prompt will be sent to STDOUT when the call is made, but that can be silenced by sending the output to `/dev/null`. The result of the command can still be stored in a variable as you might expect.

```
<?php
//Kill a sudo session if one exists.
exec('sudo -k');

//Run sudo without authenticating
$output = exec('sudo echo "foo"');
var_dump($output); //string(0) ""

//Provide the password and pipe it into sudo.
$output = exec('echo "password" | sudo -S echo "foo" 2> /dev/null');
var_dump($output); //string(3) "foo"
?>
```

Comment: You don't have to enter the password if you specify NOPASSWD for the respective command. It works now. My mistake was I thought after the command, I can specify a blank separated list of allowed arguments such as `start stop`. However, that is not a list but the exact arguments expected, so I had to specify `/path/to/executable start, /path/to/executable stop`

Comment: @smares, Interesting! I did not know that - glad to hear you found the solution. I'll keep this answer here because I think it's applicable for future searchers, I couldn't find a question with a title similar to yours.